# how can a selected dropdownlist item can be stored in a variable after disabling the dropdownlist?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to store the selected item of dropdownlist into database and after selecting it the dropdownlist should be disabled....

My problem is before disabling it am able to store the selected option. but after disaling am unable to retrieve the selected option into a variable.so that i can store it in db.....

Comment: how to use readonly to select tag

Answer (score 0):

if you use disabled input and need to be value send, add

```
<input type="hidden" name="input-name" value="value-to-be-send">
```

to your form

Comment: where to place this tag so that it performs action to dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax - here jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $("#mysel").on("change",function() {
    if (this.selectedIndex>1) { // something selected 
      $.post("dbsave.php",{"sel":$(this).val()},function() {
        ("#mysel").prop("disabled",true);
      });
    }
   });
 });
```